# SQL Select query - Item can not be found in the collection to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have the following block of code that I got from a site

```vb
Sub RunSELECT()
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String

    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With


    '---Run the SQL SELECT Query---
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [Shops$] WHERE ShopCode > 6000" 
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

    Do
       output = output & rs(0) & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & vbNewLine
       Debug.Print rs(0); ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2)
       rs.Movenext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
    MsgBox output

    '---Clean up---
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code above runs fine, but when I change the select statement to:

```
sql = "SELECT [Shops$].[ShopCode] FROM [Shops$] WHERE ShopCode > 6000"
```

I get the error

> Item can not be found in the collection to the requested name or
>   ordinal

I have tried many things for hours now including deleting my colm headers and trying different things, but I do not seem to be able to get it to recognize my colm headers.

Comment: Did you amend the `output` line to only return one field?

Comment: @Rory This is definitely the problem.  Mind as well answer.

Comment: No, I know a bit of MySQL with PHP but have just started to learn using sql in Excel, and I have no idea what you mean... But I have only changed the one line that I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only selecting one field, you cannot then refer to 3 of them in the later code, so you need to amend these lines:

```
   output = output & rs(0) & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & vbNewLine
   Debug.Print rs(0); ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2)
```

to perhaps this:

```
   output = output & rs(0) & vbNewLine
   Debug.Print rs(0)
```

Comment: That was it thank you, I should have read past the error a bit more...  :(